# Getting the proper Xpath for ImportXML OR Xpathonurl functions (Google Sheets or Excel)

Tags: html, excel, xpath, google-sheets

I am new at all this and for the life of me I cannot get the text "In Stock Online" or "Out of Stock Online from http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/large-kick-fetch-ball/6000105718024

I've tried multiple variations with no luck. 
Should it not be =importxml("url","//span[@class='msg']")   ?

This also doesnt work using Excel's xpathonurl function (an add-in)

Here is the html source code:

```
<div class="product-avail wgrid-3w6 wgrid-2w4 marg-r-0"> 
<div class="statuses"> 
<div class="shipping status">
<span class="icon-status checkmark"></span>
<span class="msg">In stock online</span>** </div>
<div class="shipping-alert status">
<span class="icon-status arrow" style="display: inline;"></span>
<span class="msg"><span class="edd"> 
<a href="javascript:void(0)">See estimated delivery date</a></span></span> </div> </div> </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=importxml("url","//span[@class='msg']/text()")
```

As per xpath, if you want to retrieve the text value of the given element, you should use text() method.

**Update**:

The span with class=msg in the given URL has an empty value. So you can handle the #N/A as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/large-kick-fetch-ball/6000105718024", "//span[@class='msg']"), "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I have tried that to no success:
`importxml(ʺurl,ʺ//span[@class='msg']/text()ʺ)`
Google returns #N/A and "Import Internal Error" message... sigh... any other suggestions?

Comment: Okay, what I see is that the <span class='msg'> doesn't have any text in it. That element is empty. I tried with //span[@class='userFirstName'] and it perfectly returns the value.

Comment: Thanks again. This is my first attempt at xpath and trying to do something useful with it so I like knowing what is going on as well. Is the cell being empty have anything to do with javascript? 
If you hit F12 that brings up the html after it has been executed (or something like that?) does that help at all with why it is empty?
And for your solution with IFERROR... I need the output to say whether it is in stock or not, and update automatically, so I am missing on how that helps. However it could be me, like I said I am a newb to all of this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960135/extracting-json-within-a-function-within-a-script-into-google-sheets. I updated the question with what I have learned and the current roadblock.